# How to "hover over" the button in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, hover

How to add hover for element? Consider my below code:

```
package AutomationFramework;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class LoginPage {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create a new instance of the Firefox driver

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Put a Implicit wait

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        //Launch the Website

        driver.get("URL");

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account'(My Account) 

       // driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[5]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")).click();

        // Enter Username on the element 

        driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("remote"); 

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'pwd' (Password)

        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("aaaaaa");

        // Now submit the form. WebDriver will find the form for us from the element 

        driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();

        // Print a Log In message to the screen

        System.out.println(" Login Successfully");
        driver.findElement(By.name("img2")).click();

        // Find the element that's ID attribute is 'account_logout' (Log Out)

        //driver.findElement (By.name("img104")).click();

        // Close the driver

        driver.quit();

            }

    }
```

Comment: What is the element that you want to hover over? Please specify.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go with `Action` class.

```
Actions hover = new Actions(driver);

WebElement Elem_to_hover = driver.findElementBy(By.id("id"));

hover.moveToElement(Elem_to_hover);

hover.build();

hover.perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Shruthi , please refer below sample program to mouse hover using selenium web driver :

```
public class mhover {

public static void main(String[] args){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfba"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(ele).build().perform();


    }

}
```

Please let me know if you have any query.